# Highcharts : How can i move the tooltip to external DIV?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to use such function which I can move the tool-tip according to the position or movment of mouse pointer in a column chart, not in a line chart.

In jQuery we have `mousemove` function but there is no such function in Highchart.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

you can move the tool tip content to any div you want

```
     tooltip:{
                 formatter : function() {
                 $("#date").html( Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/ %e/ %Y', this.x));
                 $("#data").html(this.y) ;
                         return false ;
                         }
                    },
```

and then you can apply any event to these selectors using jquery